# Microsoft Graph returns "Internal Server Error" on request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I am trying to get my Microsoft Teams assignments through Microsoft Graph. I submit this GET request `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/me/classes/{id}/assignments` as shown in the docs, with my authentication token as a header. However, below is the reply I get. I am doing this with python, however I have also tried from Graph Explorer which yields the same result.

```
{
"error": {
  "code": "InternalServerError",
  "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "innerError": {
    "date": "2020-09-07T16:44:48",
    "request-id": "011086a0-9240-4896-9363-d403a1a0fb05"
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody have any insight? Is this a problem with Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `/me`. The correct URI is `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/classes/{id}/assignments`.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationclass-post-assignments?view=graph-rest-beta#request)

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/classes/11019/assignments
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 279

{ 
  "dueDateTime": "2014-02-01T00:00:00Z",
  "displayName": "Midterm 1",
    "instructions":  {
      "contentType": "text",
      "content": "Read chapters 1 through 3"
    },
      "grading": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.education.assignments.api.educationAssignmentPointsGradeType",
        "maxPoints": 100
      },
      "assignTo": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.education.assignments.api.educationAssignmentClassRecipient"
      },
      "status":"draft",
      "allowStudentsToAddResourcesToSubmission": true
}
```